# What are the algorithms to find all numbers consisting 3 and 5 only in the given range L and R (both inclusive)

Tags: c++, numbers, binary-tree

We have to find out all the numbers consisting of 3 and 5 only in a given range L and R(inclusive).

What are the possible approaches to do this task?

Given that,

1 <= L <= R <= 10^9.

Comment: I have a solution but I am finding it difficult to implement. I just want to know is there is any other approach to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious approach would be to synthesize numbers systematically until you produced one larger than the specified maximum.

In this case, you'd produce something like: `3`, `5`, `33`, `35`, `53`, `55`, `333`, `335`, `353`, `355`, etc. until you get to one larger than 10<sup>9</sup>.

Hint: since you only have two possible digits, you could think of this as counting in binary, but convert each number using `3` in place of `0` and `5` in place of `1` (then compare the result to 10<sup>9</sup> to see if you're done yet).